# Filtering by machine type in GCP

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to filter the list of instance based on the machine type. However this doesn't seem to work.

```
Compute.Instances.List request = computeService.instances().list("project-name","us-central1-a" );
request.setFilter("(machinetype = zones/us-central1-a/machineTypes/n1-standard-1)");

InstanceList instanceList = request.execute();
List<Instance> instances = instanceList.getItems();
```

The response is empty even though, I have an instance that match the filter! (when I remove the filter it gets the instance.)

```
[chaker@cbenhamed:~]$ gcloud compute instances list                                                                                                                                                                                      
NAME                                          ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP    STATUS                                                                                                                   
foo-bar-worker-n1-standard-1-65304152130-zfq  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1  true         10.240.0.2   00.000.00.255  RUNNING
```

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list), the **filter** parameter should work in this case. Because, first the machineType is in the root of the Instance object. And second that's the right form of the machineType argument

> Full or partial URL of the machine type resource to use for this instance, in the format: zones/zone/machineTypes/machine-type. This is provided by the client when the instance is created.

I tried to inspect HTTP requests made by **gcloud**

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter="machineType:n1-standard-1" --log-http
```

But it turned out that it gets the whole list (across all zones!) and filter them locally!

Comment: I've checked through [API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/instances/m/compute/v1/compute.instances.list)
It returns non-empty machines list only if I specify full machine-type:
`machineType="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-name>/zones/europe-west1-b/machineTypes/g1-small"`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a misunderstanding, the documentation describes the **machineType** as an argument of the **Response body** no as a filter.  So in this case you can't use a partial URL also you can only use the following comparison operators =, !=, >, or < which none of them works as a like.

I think the only way to use this filter is using the full URL just as [Oleksandr Bushkovskyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4888849/oleksandr-bushkovskyi) commented:

machineType="https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/[PROJECT]/zones/[ZONE]/machineTypes/[MACHINE_TYPE]"